# Decide if functions are in $L^1(\mathbb R),L^2(\mathbb R),L^\infty(\mathbb R)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

Let $c>0$ fixed.

Let $f(x)=\begin{cases}1,&& x\in[-c,c]\\0&& \mathrm {otherwise}\end{cases}$

$g(x)=\begin{cases}2-|x|,&& x\in[-2c,2c]\\0&& \mathrm {otherwise}\end{cases}$

$h(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)e^{-itx}dt$

$i(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(t)e^{-itx}dt$

I need to decide if $f,g,h,i$ are in $L^1(\mathbb R),L^2(\mathbb R),L^\infty(\mathbb R)$.

$f$ clearly is in $L^1(\mathbb R),L^2(\mathbb R),L^\infty(\mathbb R)$.

For $g$ I would say that $|g|$ and $|g^2|$ are continuous functions with compact support so $g$ is in $L^1(\mathbb R),L^2(\mathbb R)$. And $g(x)\le 2+|x|\le2+2c$ so it is in $L^\infty(\mathbb R)$.

Is that correct so far?

What's the best way to the same for $h$ and $i?$

Comment: $h(x)=2\sin (ct)$ by direct computation. This function is in $L^{\infty}$ but not in $L^{1}$ or $L^{2}$. Similarly you can handle $i(x)$ by evaluating it first.

Comment: Don't we have $h(x)=2 \frac{\sin(cx)}{x}$?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Actually, $h$ is in $L^{\infty} \cap L^{2}$ but not in $L^{1}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you integrate  you have that $h(x)=\frac{\sin{cx}}{x}$

So $h$ is not in $L^1$

But $\int_|h|^2 \leq \int_{\{|x|>1\}}|h|^2+\int_{\{|x| \leq 1\}}|h|^2<+\infty$

because $h(x)$ is bounded in $[-1,1]$(Note the limit of $h$ exist at zero)

Clearly $h \in L^{\infty}$

$i(x)=C_1\frac{\sin{(2cx)}}{x}+2\frac{1-\cos{(2cx)}}{x^2}=C_1\frac{\sin{(2cx)}}{x}+\frac{2\sin^2{(cx)}}{x^2}$ for some constant $C_1 \in \Bbb{R}$

Similarly examine $i(x)$

Comment: $h$ is bounded on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @Yes i know..it was a typo..thank you for the correction.

Comment: @MariosGretsas How do you see $2\frac{1-\cos(2cx)}{x^2}$?

Comment: @user711482 what do you mean with ''how do you see it'' do you mean how i derived it?

Comment: @MariosGretsas Yes

Comment: @user711482 just do the integration.

Comment: @MariosGretsas We have $\int_{-2c}^{2c}(2-|t|)e^{-itx}dt=\frac{4\sin(2cx)}{x}+\int_{-2c}^{2c}|t|e^{-itx}dt$. And that last integral equals $2\frac{1-\cos(2cx)}{x^2}$ according to you?

Comment: Yes if i am not wrong in my caclulations